# how will spring mongodbtemplate check if object already exists

Tags: mongodb, spring-mongo

I am using save method in mongdbtemplate of spring mongo(api link provided below).

http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#save(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)

I am trying to understand how will mongdbtemplate check if object is already existing.
I am assuming the it uses equals method on object passed, please let me know if it is otherwise

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic code that mongodbtemplate uses internally. MongoDB natively supports the concept of **[upsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/update/#update-operations-with-the-upsert-flag)**.